# Ordering references manually using Jabref

Tags: biblatex, sorting, jabref

I have several records in contained in a bibliographic library managed through Jabref. But, I want to show the records in LaTeX, Texstudio, PDF based on the order that I specify. In other words, I want to show the order of Jabref records manually. I decide which record should be shown in the first, which one second, etc.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty much against the spirit of BibTeX and `biblatex` to sort the bibliography manually. An integral part of the job of BibTeX and Biber is to sort your bibliography properly according to some predefined scheme to make sure that the sorting is consistent and as intended.

If there is a way to express the sorting you desire as an algorithm based on the available entry data it should be possible to define a `biblatex` sorting template for Biber to sort the bibliography according to your wishes.

If you absolutely need full manual control, you can populate the field `sortkey` with values that can easily be sorted. In the example below I use numbers.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{pines,
  author       = {Pines, Shlomo},
  editor       = {Twersky, Isadore},
  title        = {The Limitations of Human Knowledge According to {Al-Farabi}, {ibn
                  Bajja}, and {Maimonides}},
  date         = 1979,
  booktitle    = {Studies in Medieval {Jewish} History and Literature},
  publisher    = {Harvard University Press},
  location     = {Cambridge, Mass.},
  pages        = {82-109},
  sortkey      = {01},
}
@thesis{geer,
  author       = {de Geer, Ingrid},
  title        = {Earl, Saint, Bishop, Skald~-- and Music},
  type         = {phdthesis},
  institution  = {Uppsala Universitet},
  date         = 1985,
  subtitle     = {The {Orkney Earldom} of the Twelfth Century. {A} Musicological
                  Study},
  location     = {Uppsala},
  sortkey      = {04},
}
@book{nussbaum,
  author       = {Nussbaum, Martha},
  title        = {Aristotle's \mkbibquote{De Motu Animalium}},
  date         = 1978,
  publisher    = {Princeton University Press},
  location     = {Princeton},
  sortkey      = {03},
}
@book{worman,
  author       = {Worman, Nancy},
  title        = {The Cast of Character},
  date         = 2002,
  publisher    = {University of Texas Press},
  location     = {Austin},
  subtitle     = {Style in {Greek} Literature},
  shorttitle   = {Cast of Character},
  sortkey      = {05},
}
@article{sigfridsson,
  author       = {Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf},
  title        = {Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
                  electrostatic potential and moments},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Computational Chemistry},
  date         = 1998,
  volume       = 19,
  number       = 4,
  pages        = {377-395},
  doi          = {10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P},
  sortkey      = {02},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,pines,geer,nussbaum,worman}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sorted bibliography: <code>pined</code>, <code>sigfridsson</code>, <code>nussbaum</code>, <code>geer</code>, <code>worman</code>]